# Split list of dictionaries into chunks

Tags: python, django, list, split

I have a python list with two list inside(one for each room - there are 2 rooms), with dictionaries inside.

How can i transform this:

```
A = [
        [{'rate': Decimal('669.42000'), 'room': 2L, 'name': u'10% OFF'}, 
         {'rate': Decimal('669.42000'), 'room': 2L, 'name': u'10% OFF'}, 
         {'rate': Decimal('632.23000'), 'room': 2L, 'name': u'15% OFF'}, 
         {'rate': Decimal('632.23000'), 'room': 2L, 'name': u'15% OFF'}], 
        [{'rate': Decimal('855.36900'), 'room': 3L, 'name': u'10% OFF'}, 
         {'rate': Decimal('855.36900'), 'room': 3L, 'name': u'10% OFF'}]
]
```

Into This:

```
A = [
        [{'rate': Decimal('669.42000'), 'room': 2L, 'name': u'10% OFF'}, 
         {'rate': Decimal('669.42000'), 'room': 2L, 'name': u'10% OFF'}],
        [{'rate': Decimal('632.23000'), 'room': 2L, 'name': u'15% OFF'}, 
         {'rate': Decimal('632.23000'), 'room': 2L, 'name': u'15% OFF'}], 
        [{'rate': Decimal('855.36900'), 'room': 3L, 'name': u'10% OFF'}, 
         {'rate': Decimal('855.36900'), 'room': 3L, 'name': u'10% OFF'}]
]
```

I need to create in the main list, three lists inside. one for each type of promo.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), you could use this nested comprehension:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from pprint import pprint

>>> x = [list(g) for l in A for k, g in groupby(sorted(l))]
>>> pprint(x)
[[{'name': u'10% OFF', 'rate': Decimal('669.42000'), 'room': 2L},
  {'name': u'10% OFF', 'rate': Decimal('669.42000'), 'room': 2L}],
 [{'name': u'15% OFF', 'rate': Decimal('632.23000'), 'room': 2L},
  {'name': u'15% OFF', 'rate': Decimal('632.23000'), 'room': 2L}],
 [{'name': u'10% OFF', 'rate': Decimal('855.36900'), 'room': 3L},
  {'name': u'10% OFF', 'rate': Decimal('855.36900'), 'room': 3L}]]
```

You can provide a key function to both `sorted` and `groupby` (preferably the same) in order to group by a specific property:

```
from operator import itemgetter
fnc = itemgetter('rate')  # if you want to group by rate
x = [list(g) for l in A for k, g in groupby(sorted(l, key=fnc), key=fnc)]
```

Comment: Great answer, and I upvoted for it, but if I understand it correctly, it only works as is because the second sublist in `A` has both different room and rate. If there were additional items there with, say, room 3 and rate 669.42, they wouldn't be grouped together with the other items having the same rate. This is easily solved by `itertools.chain`ing `A`.

Comment: `[list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(chain.from_iterable(A), key=fnc), key=fnc)]`